# PHP search and echo specific text

Tags: php, search, scripting, echo

I'm having a problem. What I want to do is make my PHP code do a search until it finds what was entered. For example if I searched the number "12." I want it to go in a file like the one below and find the line that has "12" in it.

```
Dark Green = 11 = No = 20,
Light Blue = 12 = No = 20,
Lime Green = 13 = No = 20,
Sensei Gray = 14 = Yes = 0,
```

In that case this line would have the 12 in it:

```
Light Blue = 12 = No = 20,
```

Next what I want the code to do after it finds the line is for it to read the text that is before the "=" sign to the left of it. In this case I would want my code to read:

```
Light Blue
```

I've always wanted to do this and any help would be HIGHLY appreciated!

Comment: You should use the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Comment: It looks like you might need a database table, and not a file.

Comment: How big is the file and how often does it get updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
$string = 'Dark Green = 11 = No = 20,
Light Blue = 12 = No = 20,
Lime Green = 13 = No = 20,
Sensei Gray = 14 = Yes = 0';


$string = explode(',',$string);
foreach($string as $row)
{
    preg_match('/^(\D+)\s=\s(\d+)\s=\s(\D+)\s=\s(\d+)/', trim($row), $matches);
    echo $matches[1];//Dark Green
    echo $matches[2];//11
    echo $matches[3];//No
    echo $matches[4];//20
}
```

In the loop use to check the word to search

Like that

```
if($matches[1] == 'Dark Green')
{
   echo $matches[1];
}
```

or

```
   if($matches[2] == 11)
    {
       echo $matches[2];
    }
```

(...)
To get the text in the file try use

```
    $string = file_get_contents('file.txt');
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Although, the $matches[1] part won't work for text that has numbers in it. How can make it so it works with numbers too?

Answer (score 0):

In broad terms, you can use php fgets command to process any text file line by line. Then, you can run an operation on each line, using explode as suggested above to find your string and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$lines = explode("\n",$filetext);
$searchString = preg_quote('12','/');
foreach($lines as $line) {
    preg_match("/([^=])\s*=\s*$searchString/");
    if($matches[1]) {
         print $matches[1]; 
         break;
    }
}
```

where $filetext has the text in it either using fgets to read line by line (then you don't need explode) or even simpler using file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mixture of preg_grep and explode.

```
$arr = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt'));
$matches = preg_grep('/12/', $arr);
```

Your matches would be in the $matches array;

Comment: Yes, but if you use fgets to load partial parts of the file into a buffer then you may miss a match.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$data = file("file.txt");
$num = 12;
foreach((array)$data as $key=>$line) {
   if (strstr($line,"= $num ") || strstr($line," = $num,")) {
      echo $line;
      break;
   }
}
```