# PHP search array line

Tags: php, search, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP search and echo specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954439/php-search-and-echo-specific-text)

I'm having a problem. What I want to do is make my PHP code do a search until it finds what was entered. For example if I searched the number "12." I want it to go in a file like the one below and find the line that has "12" in it.

```
Dark Green = 11 = No = 20,
Light Blue = 12 = No = 20,
Lime Green = 13 = No = 20,
Sensei Gray = 14 = Yes = 0,
```

After it has found the line, I want my code to echo the line that has "12" in it. So this would come up:

```
Light Blue = 12 = No = 20,
```

Please help me!

Comment: What code have you written and what problems are you facing with it?

Comment: Please do not open multiple duplicate questions. Instead, focus on your existing questions. If you need to add information, you can edit your own question. And if you think it needs more attention, edit it to bump it, and when you have more reputation, offer a bounty for it.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, in this question I don't want to read any specific part of the file.

Comment: @Gokhan137: It's practically the same. If you get an answer on the other, you should be able to answer this one.

Answer (score 1):

Read all lines from a file using [file](http://php.net/file):

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
```

Loop through all lines and search for a substring using [strpos](http://php.net/strpos):

```
$search = 12;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
        printf('Found %s in %s', $search, $line);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this: (assuming file.txt holds your info)

```
$num = 12;
$data = file("file.txt");
foreach((array)$data as $key=>$line) {
   if (strstr($line,"= $num ") || strstr($line," = $num,")) {
      echo $line;
      break;
   }
}
```