# PHP search and display results with keywords

Tags: php, search, scripting

What I want to do is that I have a file that looks like this:

```
Blue = 1 = No = 20,
Arctic color = 2 = No = 20,
Pink = 3 = No = 20,
Arctic blue color = 4 = No = 20,
Red = 5 = No = 20,
Orange = 6 = No = 20,
```

Lets say a users types the phrase "arctic color" into a form. What I want my code to do is to display all of the lines that have the phrase "arctic color" in it. So the code should echo:

```
Arctic color = 2 = No = 20,
Arctic blue color = 4 = No = 20,
```

How do I accomplish this though? Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated!

Comment: So you want to take the first word of a query and search for it? Does the search term need to be at the start of the line? Come on, give us more details.

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I want to take the full search query and find if any of the words in the query are found in any of the lines of the file. If they are, I want the script to echo the lines that have any one of the words from the query in it.

Comment: This sort of structured data is typically kept in a SQL database rather than a text file.  That makes sophisticated queries much easier and more efficient.

Comment: I agree with you on this, although it wouldn't make too much difference to performance since doing a `LIKE '%word%'` query always does a full table scan. Depending on the number of rows your table has, this may not be an issue though.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954439/php-search-and-echo-specific-text

Answer (score 1):

I would advise storing structured data in a database of some sort. For example, mysql.
Then you could just issue a `LIKE` query. With a wildcard on the left, this performs a full table scan, which might not be an issue depending on the number of rows you have.

If you need a more high-performance solution, you need to convert your data to a format that's more easily searchable.

---

**If you just want a solution to your exact question:**

To find lines with all of the words in:

```
$query = 'arctic color';

$terms = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(" ", $query)));
$results = array();

foreach(file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
    $found = true;

    foreach($terms as $term) {
        if(strpos($line, $term) === false) {
            $found = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($found) {
        $results[] = $line;
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

to find lines with some of the words in:

```
$query = 'arctic color';

$terms = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(" ", $query)));
$results = array();

foreach(file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
    $found = false;

    foreach($terms as $term) {
        if(strpos($line, $term) !== false) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($found) {
        $results[] = $line;
    }
}

print_r($results);
```